# How to redirect after logout from Laravel Middleware?

Tags: redirect, laravel-middleware

I'm writing some middleware in Laravel (version 8.0) which essentially checks for a deactivated organisation when an API route is called and it will log them out with the intention of redirecting to the sign in page with an appropriate message.

However, when the redirect runs it throws the following error:

```
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

The reason is because the API route being executed is a PUT method in this case so when it tries to run the redirect which expects a GET method it does not work.

Here is my middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
```

{

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()) {
    if($this->statusChecker::isServiceProviderDeactivated(Auth::user()['service_provider_id'])) {
        auth()->guard('web')->logout();
        (new SsoBroker())->logout();

        return response()->redirectTo('/sign-in');
    }
}

return $next($request);
```

}

The logout executes correctly (so if the user refreshes the page they are taken to the sign-in page) but the redirect does not work. I am not particularly experienced in writing middleware and I've done lots of research on this but not really finding any solutions. Since this site is a one-page react project the issue could lie there, but I am not sure. If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

change the Route method instead of put to get/post

```
Route::get('/', [Auth::class, 'login'])
```